# For Subscriptions, do you have to listen to invoice events or have to store billing info?

Tags: stripe-payments

So I'm trying to implement subscriptions via Stripe in my web app and I'm following along the docs and some example repos like this one - https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments

And in that repo, it stores the user's billing info in their DB.

I'm using Customer Portal so I don't think I need to store billing info correct?

Also in the docs it says to listen for `invoice` events - https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks

But in the example repo, it only listens to

```
  'product.created',
  'product.updated',
  'price.created',
  'price.updated',
  'checkout.session.completed',
  'customer.subscription.created',
  'customer.subscription.updated',
  'customer.subscription.deleted'
```

So,

What do your webhooks need to listen to for subscriptions,

and what kind of data do you store in your database about your user? I would rather not store billing data if I could avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

From indiehackers:
https://www.indiehackers.com/post/for-subscriptions-do-you-have-to-listen-to-invoice-events-or-have-to-store-billing-info-dadaea0ec3?commentId=-MadZ0mx7mv_xHb7Xp6v

It really depends on the structure of your pricing and your app. Do you have multiple tiers where different tiers provide access to different features? Are all users paid, or do you have a freemium tier? A number of additional factors too.

At the most basic level, you might be able to get away with just listening to

```
'customer.subscription.created',
'customer.subscription.updated',
'customer.subscription.deleted'
```

That will tell you when a subscription starts, has been renewed, and cancelled.

But, you won't be able to do anything like notifying the user if the renewal fails, say due to an expired card. That's where the invoice hooks come in - if you want to say, "your renewal happens in 3 days", etc.

In the vercel example, the product and price hooks are used where Stripe is the source of truth on products and pricing, and the products/prices are mirrored in your app. So you can go to Stripe's dashboard and create/change prices/products, and they gets pushed to your app.

I believe, even if you're using the Billing Portal, when the user registers, you'll still need to call out to Stripe and create customer record, and an initial subscription (could be a "free" subscription, or whatever), because I don't think the Billing Portal works without an active subscription - it is for changing and cancelling subscriptions, not for the initial creation. I could be wrong, it's been a bit since I've worked with that.

So, my suggestion is to wireframe/flowchart out the onboarding process, the renewal process, the upgrade/downgrade process, the cancellation process, and how/what your app needs to know about subscriptions. Once you've got that, you'll know what needs to be passed back and forth between Stripe and your app.